# Como executar uma procedure em PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Estou tentando criar uma listagem e estou tendo problema na hora de chamar a procedure de select.

Código conectando no banco:

```
<?php 
 $conexao = mysql_connect("localhost", "admin", "admin") or print (mysql_error()); 
 print "Conexão OK!"; 
 mysql_close($conexao); 
 mysql_select_db("des_arcamel", $conexao) or print(mysql_error()); 

?>
```

Código PHP

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

 <?php
 REQUIRE_ONCE "conexao.php";
 REQUIRE_ONCE "funcoes.php";


 echo $result = mysqli_query($conexao, "CALL sp_se_lista") or die("Query fail: " . mysqli_error()); die;
 ?>

<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
   <title>Estoque</title>

<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link href="boostrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Bootstrap theme -->
<link href="boostrap/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="container">  
<table class="table table-striped">
<tr>
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Código Produto</th>
    <th>Descrição</th>
    <th>Preço</th>
    <th>Quantidade Estoque</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
<tbody>
<?php
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){   


<td><?php echo $row[cod_produto] ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row[dsc_produto] ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row[preco_produto] ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row[qtd_estoque] ?></td>

 </tr>

 }
 </tbody>
 </table>
```

E a procedure no banco

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `des_arcamel`$$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `sp_se_lista`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`admin`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sp_se_lista`()
 BEGIN

SELECT 
cod_produto,
dsc_produto,
preco_produto,
qtd_estoque
FROM
estoque;

END$$

 DELIMITER ;
```

Alguém consegue ajudar?

---

Editando:

O problema está na hora de puxar a procedure, editei o código e agora tenho isso:

```
<?php
REQUIRE_ONCE "conexao.php";
REQUIRE_ONCE "funcoes.php";
$result = "CALL sp_se_lista()";
$rstSql = executeStoredProcedure($result);
while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rstSql)){   

echo $rows[cod_produto]; ?>
```

e a função é:

```
<?php

require_once ("conexao.php");

function executeStoredProcedure($strSql) {
global $conexao;
$rstExe = mysqli_query($conexao, $strSql);

}
```

Quando dou echo no REQUIRE tb não mostra nada...

Comment: Qual o erro que retorna?

Comment: As funções mysql_* não trabalham corretamente com sp

Comment: Nao mostra nenhum erro. Estou usando Notepad++. Devo usar outro?

Comment: Você está usando usando mysqli_* e mysql_* junto, nunca vai funcionar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pelo que pude observar você está misturando `mysql_*` na conexão e chamando a query com `mysqli_*`. O método que você precisa utilizar é basicamente esse:

```
        //conecta no banco
          $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "admin", "admin", "des_arcamel", "3306"); //ou 3307

          //executa o store procedure
          $result = mysqli_query($connection, 
             "CALL sp_se_lista();") or die("Erro na query da procedure: " . mysqli_error());

          //lista os resultados
          while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {   
              echo  $row[0] . "<br>\n" .
                       $row[1] . "<br>\n"; 
          }
```

Comment: Acredito que era isso mesmo, muito obrigado Ivan!